# Files imported from an absolute path not found

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a TS project with a file tree that has these files:

```
project
├── server
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── src
│       ├── index.ts
│       └── fileInside.ts
└── shared
    └── fileOutside.ts
```

e.g. in `index.ts`:

```
import { someFunc } from 'server/src/fileInside';
import { anotherFunc } from 'shared/fileOutside';
//the editor doesn't complain here and even auto-imports from these paths
```

I want to be able to import the files from an absolute path in server files, so I made my tsconfig.json like this:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "baseUrl": "..", // set to make the absolute import dir the project's root dir
    },
    "include": [
        ".", "../shared/",
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "./dist"
    ]
}
```

this `tsconfig` extends another `tsconfig` file from the project's root. I don't it's what causes the issue, but I'll add it just in case:

```
 {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": [
        "dom",
        "dom.iterable",
        "esnext"
      ],
      "allowJs": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "strict": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "noEmit": false,
      "incremental": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "jsx": "preserve",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "strictNullChecks": true,
    },
    "include": [
      "next-env.d.ts",
      "**/*.ts",
      "**/*.tsx"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
```

When I run my program I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'server/src/fileInside'
Require stack:
 - C:\vs_code_projects\TypeScript\neo_chess\server\src\index.ts
...
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

And of course, it was because of `ts-node` (?!?!)

Because ***obviously*** to have absolute imports in ts-node you have to install a package:

```
npm install --save-dev tsconfig-paths
```

and add this stuff to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
},
```

Why? Who the **** knows. That's the current state of web development for you.
Welcome to the **** show!